# Profiles not working in spring boot jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a custom spring boot jar which depends on the file "application.properties" with environment-specific variants, e.g:

```
application-dev.properties
application-qa.properties
application-uat.properties
```

I am using this jar in another spring boot project with active profile as "dev".

Currently I am not able to pick the env-specific properties. How can this be done?

An example error is:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'custom.url' in string value "${custom.url}"
```

but this works if I specify the file particularly using `@PropertySource`.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your setup. Did you add a fat jar in another fat jar by any chance? When you say spring boot jar, do you mean spring boot app?

Comment: no just a jar. not a fatjar

Answer (score 0):

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=local"`

if you use the above command then it can pick the `application-local.properties`